# Chrome or firefox extension that will mute/decrease volume at louder parts of a youtube video?

Tags: chrome, firefox

1. Examples: An advertisement video on youtube that happens to be noticeably louder than the current video you are listening to.
2. Say there is a movie on youtube. There will be quieter, more peaceful scenes then later louder more violent scenes.
3. Some youtube channels have openings at the start of every one of their videos. The opening might have music that is noticeably louder than the rest of the video.

When I'm trying to relax, sudden louder noises in something can be jarring and break the mood.

Is there some kind of extension that works with youtube to mute/drastically decrease the volume during segments described above.